# beamer presentation with enumerated list problem

Tags: beamer, numbering, lyx, enumerate

I have a beamer presentation. In the presentation I have a numbered list... within each number I have a sub-numbered list which I would like to be like the following.  How do I fix this problem?

```
1. hello
   a) hi
   b) bye

2. bye
   a) hi
   b) bye
```

But unfortunately I get this:

```
1. hello
   1. hi
   2. bye

2. bye
   1. hi
   2. bye
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item hello 
    \begin{enumerate}[a)]
    \item hi 
    \item bye
    \end{enumerate}
  \item bye
    \begin{enumerate}[a)]
    \item hi 
    \item bye
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}  

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Should want to get rid of using a package and moreover, specifying the format again and again, please set your intended format as the default one. Please see below,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\alph{enumii})}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item hello 
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item hi 
    \item bye
    \end{enumerate}
  \item bye
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item hi 
    \item bye
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}  

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you! @MMA, I am using LyX however, how would I do it there?

Comment: @Alex Sorry, but I am completely ignorant of LyX. I am an old fashioned text file and command line user. But as my general knowledge goes, there should be some way to use to use the package and modify the command inside. That is all I can guess.

Comment: I think your addition would work! could you please explain to me what it is actually doing? the `setbeamertemplate` command? I currently use it to get rid of the slide navigation: `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols`